# How to use FetchS3Object Nifi processor for MinIO

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi, minio

I am trying to use FetchS3Object Processor to fetch the S3 object placed in MinIO. Since the processor doesn't speaks with S3 service I have overridden the "Endpoint Override URL" (http://minio:9000/) property of the processor. But I get following exception:

```
eversync-ops-eversync-etl-1      | com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: . (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed; Request ID: 1773A28C133B4B95; S3 Extended Request ID: dd9025bab4ad464b049177c95eb6ebf374d3b3fd1af9251148b658df7ac2e3e8; Proxy: null)
```

I have verified my credentials and also can retrieve file content using Postman on

```
http://localhost:9000/eversync/exportgds.csv
```

Question(s) - Can I use FetchS3Object processor for MinIO? If not what is the workaround - use REST API?

Thanks

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using? What configuration are you using for your FetchS3 processor?

Comment: Hi @pvillard, thanks for your help. I am using nifi:1.22.0 and minio latest. My deployment is containerized and uses docker-compose. For the processor I am using same all that you mentioned in answer except that my bucket name is from an attribute in flowfile and endpoint is http://minio:9000 - where minio is the name of the service for minio.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [flow definition](https://gist.github.com/pvillard31/8403c85f743f16e3135790d073284129) that I use to test the S3 processors with MinIO.

There is nothing really specific regarding the configuration.

Everything is default configuration except for:

- Bucket
- Access Key ID / Secret Access Key
- Endpoint Override URL (ex: http://127.0.0.1:9000)

I'd double check the NiFi version you're using and the MinIO version as well.